# NetRange and Router Sharing for Pentesting

Tags: network

When pentesting a network, call it ExampleNet, the network range sometimes exceeds 256 hosts, such as the range x.y.56.0-x.y.63.255. Does this mean that a compromised host on x.y.56.z could be used to leverage a MITM attack against a range such as x.y.62.z, considering they both share the same ethernet?

Comment: Not a security question, but a basic IP networking one. 256 hosts is not any kind of limit on network size; it's just a size that used to be popular 20-30 years ago. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally depends on network setup. Some commercial switches can separate the network out into different subnets, with special routing tables between them. That way you'll have a single physical switch connecting all the machines, but you'll still have several subnets.

They may also be using technologies like ipsec to encrypt and authenticate network communications, which can make a MITM attack difficult, if not impossible.

But, if it's all on the same switch, the switch isn't doing anything "clever", and they're not using a protection technology such as ipsec, then you should be able to perform a MITM attack using a single comprimised host.